# Connect-PnPOnline : Method not found

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013

I posted this on the PnP-PowerShell github, but I am very short in time to fix this, so I am posting it here too.

**Reporting an Issue or Missing Feature**

Using a script using `Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials $cred -ErrorAction Stop` to connect to an http SP2013 as usual, but it suddenly fails. This is very close to another case https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/926 but even though I did what he did, the problem is still not solved. The script is not needed for it to fail, just using the cmdlet on its own fails too.

**Expected behavior**

Connecting to the Sharepoint site

**Actual behavior**

The script fails and gives this error:

```
"Connect-PnPOnline : Méthode introuvable: 'Void Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryRetry(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext, Int32, Int32)'.
Au caractère C:\Program Files (x86)\Provi-SP\get-template.ps1:11 : 1

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $text -Credentials $cred -ErrorAction Stop

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-PnPOnline], MissingMethodException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.MissingMethodException,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline
```

**Version of the PnP-PowerShell Cmdlets:**

PnP PowerShell for SharePoint 2013

**Version of the Cmdlet module:**

2.16.1706.1

**Installation approach for PnP-PowerShell Cmdlets:**

Installed through the PowerShell Gallery with Install-Module.

Comment: use [THIS RELEASE](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

Comment: I already am on the lastest release : 2.16.1706.1, and even after trying to reinstall it via this method, it still fails

Comment: yes, but still i would like you to download and use this. i have used this and its working fine. give it a try

Comment: I just did, and it still fails

Comment: could you go through these [Link1](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/1022) and [Link2](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/issues/1451)

Comment: @RanadipDutta I did the same, even refferenced another issue like this on my post were I tried to do thez same, but even going such length, the problem is still here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found what went wrong, and how to solve it.

First solving : I just removed all modules up to NuGet, and took everything back from scratch, that means: NuGet, PowerShellGet and its requirement, PnP module re-updated.

Secondly the issue : it seems like the cmdlet Get-PnPWebTemplate is the one working poorly, and messing with Connect-PnPOnline once used, I will inform the gitHub about this